# How to extract the whole certificate chain using openssl

Tags: network-programming, openssl

I am trying to extract a web site SSL certificate chain. I used Openssl as the following:

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname:443 -showcerts
```

But this gives me the first cetificate only. while I need the whole chain certificate. How can I achieve this please ?

Answer (score -1):

That generally means that the server is not sending the whole chain. So openssl cannot give it to you.

The best solution usually is to get what you can from that output - and then search for the Serial, DN and similar through google or through the CA's website and fetch it from there. And with that build your own, client side, chain.

Unfortunately it is very common for websites to be mis-configured.

Sorry :)

Dw.